# pgf macro used as variable for ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

in my preamble I defined

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argcosh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(-1 + \x)*sqrt(1 + \x));}}
```

and I would like to use these functions for evaluating axis of ellipse like this:

```
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\elipseA}{sinh((1/4)*\argsinh(1))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\elipseB}{0.4}
    \draw[thin] (0,1,0) arc (90:270:{\elipseA} and {\elipseB});
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

I tried almost everything, but I am not able to figure out where the problem is.
Any help is welcome

Comment: you need to remove the backslash from declared functions, just `...(1/4*argsinh(1))`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `argsinh(1)` instead of `\argsinh(1)`?

Comment: Yes. Even though it was trivial, you really saved my time. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it caused by a typo.